# What would be the most efficient and fastest way to remove an element from a nested ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of ArrayLists implemented as:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> sampleList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Supposing that my list, after some operations, contains the following elements:

```
[[1,2,3],[2,1,3,4],[3,1,2],[4,2]]
```

I want to remove all occurrences of a particular element, say 4, from this collection, i.e., I want to obtain the following output after the removal of 4:

```
[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[3,1,2]]
```

I know I can use a **for** loop, but that would be too tedious and inefficient in cases of a really large set. 
So is there a better method to do this? (I'm new to programming)

Comment: You cannot know an element exists until you visit it (or don't).

Comment: Use Sets instead of Lists.

Comment: So I have to use a for loop then, to check the complete set?

Comment: Unless you have serious requirements in terms of performance, I think you shouldn't care too much about inefficiency in this case. A famous software engineering quote is 'premature optimization is the root of all evil'. With modern CPU's, you are probably better off spending your valuable time in a different way. It all depends on the exact case of course.

Comment: Unless you have measured that you have a performance issue chances are you are just guessing, and you don't.  You should concentrate on making your code simple and clear and it is likely to be fast enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your stated requirements, there's not going to be a better solution.  You'll need to be a bit careful to avoid removing the value 4 instead of the element at position 4:

```
Set<String> toRemove = Collections.singleton(4);
for (List<Integer> list : sampleList) {
  list.removeAll(toRemove);
}
```

Comment: Considering he's stating inefficiency as a downside to regular looping, you may want to define the singleton outside of the for loop here.